# Not able to find Viewbin and cvrtbin exe

Tags: windows-ce, platform-builder

I have to make Wince6.0 image, so i installed Platform-builder 6.0 to the system, created the nk.bin file now i need to convert it to nk.nb0 file, but i am not able to find viewbin and cvrtbin file, Platform-builder is installed in the system. Any input will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In general they are under current folder :

> %WINCEROOT%\PUBLIC\COMMON\OAK\BIN\I386

Answer (score 0):

If you open a command prompt using the "Build\Open Release Directory" option of VS menu you should be able to invoke them directly since the folder that Paolo mentioned is automatically added to the PATH.